# How to send binary data?

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I am using Mosquito MQTT server to broadcast messages.

How can I send a binary data (not text)?

Example:

```
mosquitto_pub -t test -m 0x452343
```

Should be received as:

```
0100 0101 0010 011 0100 0011
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could put your binary data in a file, then send the file as a message:

```
mosquitto_pub -t test -f file
```

Or you could write your own client using libmosquitto or another MQTT client library.

Answer (score 12):

If you literally want to send that binary sequence of characters, then you can use echo to convert from a string to binary using:

```
echo -ne "\x45\x23\x43" | mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -t 'test/binary' -s
```

This also works for the output of binary commands, such as capturing an image on a Raspberry Pi:

```
raspistill -o - | mosquitto_pub -h test.mosquitto.org -t 'webcam/' -s
```